# how to get random value in struts set tag

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

Im using struts2 tags for my application. I need to change the value randomly from script to s:set tag and populate into the javascript array. If i add dynamically means i get the output as **2012 - diff + 1** but my expected output as **2011** . How can i achieve this, my code is

```
var threeDatas = [];
var prevyear = [];
var diff;
var flagthree = false;

<% int j = 0;%>

<s:iterator value="testlist">
    prevyear.push(<s:property value="year"/>);
    if (<%= j - 1%> !== -1) {
        if (prevyear[<%= j - 1%>] !== prevyear[<%= j%>] - 1) {
            diff = prevyear[<%= j%>] - prevyear[<%= j - 1%>];
        }
        if (diff > 1) {                                                   
            for (inc = 1; inc < diff; inc++) {
                <s:set var="incyear"> <s:property value="year"/> - diff+1</s:set>
                 threeDatas.push(['<s:property value="#incyear"/>', null, null]);
            }
            flagthree = true;
            diff = 0;
        }

<% j++;%>

</s:iterator>
```

i need my final array value should be link

```
['x', 'Cats','Dogs'],
     ['2008',   10, null],
     ['2009',   20, null],
     ['2010',   null, null],
     ['2011',   null, 23],
     ['2012',   null, 34]
```

Comment: Don't mix concepts (Javascript is executed on the client, the rest on the server), Don't put business logic in the view, Don't use scriptlets. Since you are using Struts2, the Action is exactly the place where to put all that stuff.

Comment: but i need this logic in the client side, is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of logic is that, but are you aware that for each element of testlist, you will get the entire code posted here (between the iterator) duplicated ? If you have 100 elements, you will have 100 if... if... for()... blocks. I'm not sure that is what you want.

Comment: Try editing your question by adding the use-case: what you have, what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the eval() method in JavaScript. So, if you can generate something like

`var incyear = eval('<s:property value="year"/> - diff + 1');`

Comment: i've added the eval method as like your advice and place like <s:set var="incyear"> incyear </s:set> but my output is **incyear** itself. it is not displaying the value from set tag

Comment: Try this: threeDatas.push([eval('<s:property value="year"/> - diff + 1') + "", null, null]);

Comment: To know what I meant, you can try this JavaScript: var a= 45; alert(eval('1 + a + 45'));

Answer (score 0):

i found another way, by using set

```
<s:set var="incyear"> <s:property value="year"/> - diff+1</s:set>
                 threeDatas.push([<s:property value="#incyear"/>+"", null, null]);
```

and the code below :

```
var threeDatas = [];
var prevyear = [];
var diff;
var flagthree = false;
<% int j = 0;%>


<s:iterator value="testlist">
    prevyear.push(<s:property value="year"/>);
    if (<%= j - 1%> !== -1) {
        if (prevyear[<%= j - 1%>] !== prevyear[<%= j%>] - 1) {
            diff = prevyear[<%= j%>] - prevyear[<%= j - 1%>];
        }
        if (diff > 1) {                                                   
            for (inc = 1; inc < diff; inc++) {
                <s:set var="incyear"> <s:property value="year"/> - diff+1</s:set>
                 threeDatas.push([<s:property value="#incyear"/>+"", null, null]);
            }
            flagthree = true;
            diff = 0;
        }

<% j++;%>

</s:iterator>
```

by using this you can get the output as

```
['x', 'Cats','Dogs'],
 ['2008',   10, null],
 ['2009',   20, null],
 ['2010',   null, null],
 ['2011',   null, 23],
 ['2012',   null, 34]
```